# Watch ng-click on data loaded from ajax query

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an AngularJS service that opens a search prompt, performs query, shows the search results and allows the user to select an item.

The problem I am having is when I show the search results, I can not get the ng-click to work.  In my search results list, the user can click on the value which is an html anchor with ng-click to select that item.  When the user clicks on the item they want, I can not get the ng-click function to be called.  When I click on the anchor with ng-click, nothing happens.

The following code is the angularjs-ui-bootstrap event 'rendered' after showing the search results modal.  I am taking the json search results and presenting them in a jquery datatable.  In 'createdRow', I am trying to add the watcher for ng-click, but it is not working.

How can I get the ng-click function to call from my search results?

```
// after the modal window is rendered, set the data and datatable
_instance.rendered.then(function() {
  console.log('searchService.showResults.rendered.then;');
  $('#searchresultsmodaltable').dataTable({
    info: false,
    searching: false,
    ordering: false,
    lengthChange: false,
    autowidth: true,
    pageLength: 6,
    pagingType: "simple_numbers",
    language: {
      emptyTable: "No results found."
    },
    data: _results,
    columns: [{
      data: "codeHtml",
      title: "Code"
    }, {
      data: "name",
      title: "Name"
    }],
    createdRow: function(row, data, dataIndex) {
      console.log('searchService.showResults.createdRow;');
      $compile(angular.element(row).contents())($scope);
    }
  });
});
```

Plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/BAtlRpVR2MBPfXr7wmJq?p=preview

To replicate the problem in the plunker code:

1. Click on the 'search' button to open the search input modal.
2. Click on the 'search' button to show the search results modal.
3. In the search results, you will see 'code2'.  If you click on 'code2', nothing happens.  The html anchor is set with ng-click="onClickSelect('code2')", but that event does not fire when clicked. If you look at line 70 in the plunker code, that is where I am taking the search results and putting them into the datatable.  Line 93 is where I am trying to add the ng-click watcher that is not working.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check `z-index` of `.modal` in `css`? I've had same problem in `modal`, but after modified `z-index` and `tab-index`, mine was gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved your problem. 
Look at your code, the controller is used twice (two uibModal). Every controller will have a new scope, so the scope you pass into `showResult` func is the old one.

To fix your code, separate your controller, and move `showResult` to the second one.

Comment: Thanks for response.  Not referencing the correct controller was my problem.  I fixed my code a little different than your suggestion.  In my controller I provided the service a reference to the scope and compile to make it work.  Thanks.